# Bootstrap 2 columns, 2 background extended

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, background, multiple-columns

I'm trying to get a `container` with two columns with different `background-color`s. And I want the `background` of each column to extend out of their own `container`.

I tried this, but I don't know if this is the correct answer; should I use a `overflow: hidden`?

[CodePen Example](http://codepen.io/antoine_brreton/pen/RGWOEd)

```css
#skills {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

#skills-box {
    background-color: #1a1a1a;
    padding-right: 130px;
}

#skills-box, #time-box {
    min-height: 300px;
}

#skills-box:before,
#time-box:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 999em;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

#skills-box:before {
    left: -999em;
    background: #1a1a1a;
}

#time-box:before {
    right: -999em;
    background: #ccca14;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 40px;
}

#time-box {
    background-color: #ccca14;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="skills">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8" id="skills-box">
            <h2>Compétences</h2>

            <!-- skills bar in JS here -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4" id="time-box">
            <h2>Je suis dans le web depuis:</h2>
            <p id="dev-time">

             <!-- dev time in JS here -->
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, indeed, overflow-x: hidden seems to be a good idea, and it works for me ! :)

Answer (score 0):

You really should be using background colors on your body and containers to handle things like this and not mess with bootstrap's column width and overflow. That's going to cause you a lot of headaches down the road.

Since you're using breakpoints to stack your columns you can specify a solid background color for body or some other wrapper around your content, and make sure your rows are full width.

When you get to the larger breakpoint point (where your columns are side-by-side and your row has a fixed width), and you want the grey on the left to go all the way to the left and the green on the right to go all the way to the right, you can get a little creative with CSS background gradients to achieve what you're after.

For instance here's a gradient applied to the body that is half grey, half green. Your content could sit directly over top of it, and if it's left column has the gray background and the right column has the green background it will achieve the effect you're after without monkeying up your columns:

```css
body {    
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #1a1a1a 0%, #1a1a1a 50%, #ccca14 50%, #ccca14 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #1a1a1a 0%,#1a1a1a 50%,#ccca14 50%,#ccca14 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #1a1a1a 0%,#1a1a1a 50%,#ccca14 50%,#ccca14 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1a1a1a', endColorstr='#ccca14',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
```

This same logic could be applied to a 100% width `<section>` or other wrapper if you didn't want to apply it to the whole body.

You'll just need to implement something like this and accommodate for your breakpoints.

Answer (score 0):

From [Paulie_D's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39489891/bootstrap-2-columns-2-background-extended#comment66297975_39489891) (14 September 2016):

You would definitely need to use `overflow-x: hidden` on the body unless you can calculate the width of the pseudo-elements. I'd prefer a width of `100vw` rather than `999em`, but the effect is the same:

```css
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

#skills {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

#skills-box {
    background-color: #1a1a1a;
    padding-right: 130px;
}

#skills-box, #time-box {
    min-height: 300px;
}

#skills .col-md-8:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: calc(25vw);
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}

#time-box:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100vw;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}

#skills .col-md-8:before {
    right: 100%;
    background: #1a1a1a;
}

#time-box:before {
    left: 0;
    background: #ccca14;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 40px;
}

#time-box {
    background-color: #ccca14;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="skills">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8" id="skills-box">
            <h2>Compétences</h2>

            <!-- skills bar in JS here -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4" id="time-box">
            <h2>Je suis dans le web depuis:</h2>
            <p id="dev-time">

             <!-- dev time in JS here -->
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```